# Karush-Kuhn-Tucker in Quadratic Program

Tags: quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I read an paper on Quadratic Programming:

Paul A. Jensen, Jonathan F. Bard: Operations Research Models and Methods
 Nonlinear Programming Methods.S2
 Quadratic Programming
 Available here: [https://www.me.utexas.edu/~jensen/ORMM/supplements/methods/nlpmethod/S2_quadratic.pdf](https://www.me.utexas.edu/%7Ejensen/ORMM/supplements/methods/nlpmethod/S2_quadratic.pdf)

It defines the Quadratic Program as:

$Minimize \;\; f(x)=cx+\frac{1}{2}x^{T}Qx$

$Subject\, to\;\; Ax\leq b\;\; and\;\; x\geq 0$

On page 2 it states that the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions for this are:

(JB.1)    $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_{j}}\geq 0,\; \; j = 1,...,n\; \; \; \; \; \; c+x^{T}Q+\mu A\geq0$

(JB.2)    $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu_{i}}\leq 0,\; \; i = 1,...,m\; \; \; \; \; \; Ax-b\leq0$

(JB.3)    $x_{j}\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_{j}}=0,\; \; j = 1,...,n\; \; \; \; \; \; x^{T}\left ( c^{T}+Qx+A^{T}\mu \right )=0$

(JB.4)    $\mu_{i}g_{i}(x)=0,\;\;i=1,...,m \;\;\;\;\;\; \mu\left ( Ax-b \right )=0$

(JB.5)    $x_{j}\geq 0,\;\; j=1,...,n \;\;\;\;\;\; x\geq 0$

(JB.6)    $\mu_{i}\geq 0,\;\; i=1,...,m \;\;\;\;\;\; \mu\geq 0$

As far as I know the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (in general, not in the special case of Quadratic Programming) are these:

(KKT.Stationarity)    $\triangledown f(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{m} \mu_{i} \triangledown g_{i}(x) + \sum_{j=1}^{l} \lambda_{j} \triangledown h_{j}(x) = 0$

(KKT.PrimalFeasibility)    $g_{i}(x)\leq 0,\;\; i=1,...,m \;\; and \;\; h_{j}(x)= 0,\;\; j=1,...,n$

(KKT.DualFeasibility)    $\mu_{i}\geq 0,\;\; i=1,...,m$

(KKT.ComplementarySlackness)    $\sum_{i=1}^{m} \mu_{i}g_{i}(x)=0$

I see how the following are related:

(JB.2) and (JB.5) <=> (KKT.PrimalFeasibility) with $g(x)=\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & -I \end{bmatrix} x - \begin{bmatrix} b \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $h(x)=0$

(JB.6) <=> (KKT.DualFeasibility)

(JB.4) <=> (KKT.ComplementarySlackness)

However, I do not understand the connection between:

(JB.1), (JB.3) on the one hand and (KKT.Stationarity) on the other hand

Could you please explain me, how these follow from each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors didn't mention the multipliers (say $\lambda \ge 0$) for $x \ge $ 0 explicitly. Usually, you would have:

$c+x^{T}Q+\mu A - \lambda = 0$ and $\lambda \ge 0$ and $x_j \lambda_j = 0$

but this indeed implies

$c+x^{T}Q+\mu A \ge 0$ and $x^T (c+x^{T}Q+\mu A) = 0$

when you eliminate $\lambda = c+x^{T}Q+\mu A$.